# Generic List Find using lambda expression in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
List<Visibility> ListVisibility = new List<Visibility>();
    public class Visibility
    {
        public int ShpNo;
        public int QtyShp;
        public int NumPallets;
        public string ETA;            
    }

Visibility item = ListVisibility.Find(VisibItem => VisibItem.ETA == e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString());
```

But the above Find is not returning any Item, when there is an item that matches that condition.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there is a match for the exact string returned by `ToShortDateString`?

Comment: Could be a locale issue with the date formatting.

Comment: If you can refactor to use a `DateTime` for `ETA` instead of a string, comparisons will be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely string match does not find a match. Change code to compare dates as [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) portions of `DateTime` and it will have better chance to work.

```
item => DateTime.Parse(item.ETA).Date == e.Day.Date
```

Sample is assuming `e.Day` is `DateTime`. Also you may need to handle "`item.ETA` is not valid date/empty" case (i.e. by using `DateTime.TryParse`) to match original behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Any number of things come to mind, but two that seem most likely:

1. Is the string in `Visibility.ETA` trimmed of leading and trailing whitespace?
2. Does the case of the string in `Visibility.ETA` match that of `DateTime.ToShortDateString()`?

If you change your condition to:

```
var date = e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString();
var vis = list.Find(
    v => String.Compare(v.ETA, date, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

Does it find the item you're looking for? If not you should consider whether or not you need to convert ETA to a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Occam's razor: Your assumption that there is an item that matches your condition is incorrect.

You can verify that the method works with a simple test (this uses NUnit).

```
[Test]
public void TestFind()
{
     var etaValue = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
     var visibilities = new List<Visibility> { new Visibility { ETA = etaValue } };
     var foundItem = visibilities.Find(x => x.ETA == etaValue);
     Assert.That(foundItem, Is.Not.Null);
}
```